# Ajax подгрузка плеера

Tags: ajax

Возникла проблема при ajax подгрузке. Не работает html5 player. Может кто-то сталкивался?

Не грузит файл. Я получаю ссылку на видео, после в цикле вывожу плеера с ссылкой.Кнопка плей не активна.

```
for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
    container.innerHTML +="плеер и ссылку";
}
```

Когда только открываю страницу видео открывается все отлично, но при подгрузке уже не хочет.

Comment: в каком плане "не работает"? не грузит файл и пропадает при проигрывании, просто отсутствует, еще что-либо?

Comment: добавьте код, который правит тег плеера в вопрос

Comment: <source src="1.webm ?"<--- сюда ?   " type="video/webm">

Comment: насколько я смог понять, вы конкатенируете старый адрес источника с новым, что естественно создаст проблемы. Вставьте целиком код реакции на ответ ajax-запроса в вопрос (не в комментарий), потому что пока - только гадание по воде